# Navigator is not defined in .css/.scss files in photoswipe

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have quite an old vuejs 2 project (~2018 - 2019 year) that I need to build.

When I run `yarn build` I get the following error

[image]

1. In this project in `/src` folder there are few occurrences of navigator, but none of them are in ImageGallery.scss
2. I tried replacing projects `navigator` to `window.navigator`, it didn't help
3. If I delete ImageGallery.scss it builds correctly
4. In ImageGallery there are two imports that causes the error:

```
@import "photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.css";
@import 'photoswipe/dist/default-skin/default-skin.css';
```

If I delete both of them, it builds correctly.

5. In photoswipe plugin there are a lot of `navigator` objects, but all of them in .js files.
6. I tried switching node to the old versions (6, 8, 10) that didn't help

What I cannot understand at all is why it says that it couldn't find `navigator` in ImageGallery.scss, since it doesn't have anything with this object.

All previous attempts to google this lead to SSR/backend stuff, not to vuejs.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bit of a nightmare to debug, good luck!

Do other SCSS files also fail with the same error or just that one?

Here's a few things you can try:

1. Remove your node_modules and any cache files then install again
2. Mock navigator in your main JS file: `window.navigator = { userAgent: 'node.js' }`;
3. Explore your build's saas-loader and node-saas versions/packages - perhaps something is going on there when it's building the files.

My immediate thought is that there's some sort of conflict with Node versions and the modules, or perhaps cached files that are conflicting.